# Ошибка комплиляции простого проекта под Android в командной строке

Tags: java, android, компиляция

У меня есть самый простой проект на Java под Android с такой вот структурой:

```
HelloWorld
    assets // пусто
    bin    // пусто
    gen    // пусто
    obj    // пусто
    res
        drawable-hdpi
            icon.png
        drawable-ldpi
            icon.png
        drawable-mdpi
            icon.png
    layou
        main.xml
    values
        strings.xml
    libs
        android.jar
    src
        org
            me
                androiddemo
                    MainActivity.java
    AndroidManifest.xml
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">" 

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AndroidDemo</string>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package org.me.androiddemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.me.androiddemo"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:versionCode="1">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

    <application>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Стоит задача скомпилировать все это дело и собрать APK пакет для Android. Выполняю:

```
export PROJ=/path/to/HelloWorld

aapt package -f -m -J $PROJ/src -M $PROJ/AndroidManifest.xml -S $PROJ/res -I $PROJ/libs/android.jar
```

... после чего в проекте, конечно, создается файл R.java рядом с MainActivity.java:

```
HelloWorld
    assets // пусто
    bin    // пусто
    gen    // пусто
    obj    // пусто
    res
    layou
    values
    libs
    src
        org
            me
                androiddemo
                    MainActivity.java
                    R.java
```

R.java:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package org.me.androiddemo;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

Дальше генерируем байт код java:

```
javac -d $PROJ/obj -classpath $PROJ/src -bootclasspath $PROJ/libs/android.jar $PROJ/src/org/me/androiddemo/*.java
```

В директории obj появляются следующие файлы:

```
HelloWorld
    assets // пусто
    bin    // пусто
    gen    // пусто
    obj
        org
            me
                androiddemo
                    MainActivity.class
                    R.class
                    R$attr.class
                    R$drawable.class
                    R$layout.class
                    R$strings.class
    res
    layou
    values
    libs
    src
```

Дальше создаю classes.dex:

```
dx --dex --output=$PROJ/bin/classes.dex $PROJ/obj
```

... но получаю вот это:

```
    trouble processing:
        class name(org/me/androiddemo/MainActivity) does not match path (MainActivity.class)
        ...while parsing MainActivity.class
        ...while processing MainActivity.class

trouble processing:
    class name(org/me/androiddemo/R$attr) does not match path (R$attr.class)
    ...while parsing R$attr.class
    ...while processing R$attr.class

trouble processing:
    class name(org/me/androiddemo/R$drawable) does not match path (R$drawable.class)
    ...while parsing R$drawable.class
    ...while processing R$drawable.class

trouble processing:
    class name(org/me/androiddemo/R$layout) does not match path (R$layout.class)
    ...while parsing R$layout.class
    ...while processing R$layout.class

trouble processing:
    class name(org/me/androiddemo/R$string) does not match path (R$string.class)
    ...while parsing R$string.class
    ...while processing R$string.class

trouble processing:
    class name(org/me/androiddemo/R) does not match path (R.class)
    ...while parsing R.class
    ...while processing R.class

6 warnings
no classfiles specified
```

Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась вот так:
    dx --dex --verbose --no-strict --output=$PROJ/bin/classes.dex $PROJ/obj